# Is it possible to capture flv links in php like using tcpdump?

Tags: php, youtube, tcpdump

I am making an online videoconverter. I managed to make the youtube plugin to get the flv link but I am finding it to hard to make the other ones e.g dailymotion, so it possible to capture the streaming url using something like tcpdump because this will also mean that I dont have to update the plugin if they change the way they serve the video?

Answer (score 1):

Each video sharing site is different, you'll need to do some research on the sites of interest to get the location of their mp4/flv files.

Use a tool like Firebug and search for files loading prior to the video stream starting.

For your reference (as per your question), Dailymotion stores a file containing their video locations using this address format:

`http://cdn.dailymotion.com/cdn/{VIDEO_CODEC_DIMENSIONS}/video/{VIDEO_ID}.mp4?auth={AUTH_TOKEN}&redirect=0`

Please remember to check any legal implications of using other sites' videos.

Comment: Thanks i tried this, it works on my localhost but i cannot get this to work on my shared hosting, but the youtube plugin i made works on my shared hosting.